# Invoke scan QR code app clip experience for Testflight beta version

Tags: ios, swift, apple-appclips

I am new to app clip experience and currently struggling to deliver my demo app to my client with full app clip experience (including scan QR code to open app clip).

My question is that can we have scan QR code to open app clip card for testflight beta version? I tried to add an invocation URL for the specific testing build, but not working at all.

Here are things I have done so far:

- Scan QR code is working as expected for local registered experience, which means you must have app clip cached in your device via building from Xcode
- App & clip is submitted to Testflight for testing. I can see the open app clip from Testflight App, and my app clip works perfectly.
- I did a set of configuration about aasa file, and I can see it is configured properly
  [image]

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For testers, they launch through Testflight. Documentation says:

> Users don’t install App Clips, and App Clips don’t appear on the Home screen. Similarly, testers don’t install the beta version of your App Clip, and it also doesn’t appear on the Home screen either. **Instead, testers launch the App Clip experiences you configure for testing through the TestFlight app on their device.**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/testing_your_app_clip_s_launch_experience

Testers can configure a local experience and then launch the app clip in that way.

> Testers can also configure a local experience to launch the App Clip you distribute with TestFlight. However, you must still associate your App Clip with your website. In addition, testers must launch the App Clip from an App Clip experience for testing you configure in App Store Connect at least once to ensure that the App Clip is cached on the device.

That same documentation mentions how to setup a local experience.